# why trust wallet showes different addresses after importing the wallet from safepal?

Tags: trust, bip39

Due to some problems I need to check that if Trust wallet can be used instead of Safepal or not?!
Everything works fine after importing mnemonic phrase from trust wallet to Safepal but it did not vice versa.

Is it something related to BIP39/44?

Answer (score 0):

It could be they use different derivation paths for ETH. Ethpal seems to use [m/44h/60h/0h](https://docs.safepal.io/report-a-bug/derivation-paths-supported-by-safepal-1). Trustwallet seems to use ["m/44'/60'/0'/0/0"](https://github.com/trustwallet/developer/blob/master/wallet-core/wallet-core-usage.md).

With Trustwallet you should be able to create another wallet with a custom derivation path, try adding/removing an extra 0.